# Show total firestore documents created by a user in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

How would I go about showing the number of documents created by a user in Flutter?

I have come across this code in a stackoverflow post but unsure how to display that in text  `Firestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots().length.toString();`

Another example, this is how I'm showing the users the First letter of their name in a Fittedbox

```
FittedBox(
  fit: BoxFit.contain,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: [
            Color(0xffff8a93),
            Color(0xffffbf81)
        ],
        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
        end: Alignment.bottomRight
      ),
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
    ),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: BlocBuilder(
      cubit: BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context),
      builder: (context, User user) {
        return AutoSizeText(
          (user.firstName?.isEmpty == true) ? 
            "CN"
          : 
            '${user.firstName[0].toUpperCase()}',
            style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
              textStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  fontSize: 50,
                  color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        );
      }
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line `Firestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots().length.toString();` returns the count of all products, not from a specific user. If you want to filter your query for a specific user you can try below syntax assuming you have a `user` field in your `products` document :

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('products')
  .where('user', is: 'admin')
  .get()
  .then(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StreamBuilder` to get the data from the snapshots and get the length of the documents to display it in a `Text` widget.

Check out this sample code:

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data == null) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    } else {
      var snapshotDocumentLength = snapshot.data.documents.length;
      return Text(snapshotDocumentLength.toString());
  }
})
```

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to see the logic. How would I only show the user's documents? Would I need to put in the UID?

Comment: Yeah, you'll most likely need to put the UID depending on your db structure.